# Flip from right with delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimationtransition

I want to add an animation to my app . I have a card and i want to move it to center and after the card is there to flip from right . I used this code;

```
 [self.scrollView bringSubviewToFront:self.image1];
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
    animation.duration = 0.75;
    [self.image1.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"kCATransitionFade"];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.image1.frame = CGRectMake(90,self.scrollView.frame.origin.y+40, 140, 250);
    }];
    self.image1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1,0.1);

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.image1];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeInNewView" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    self.image1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2,2);
    self.image1.alpha = 1.0f;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    UIImage *imageTest=[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];


    [UIView transitionWithView:self.image1 duration:1
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
                           self.image1.image = imageTest;
                       } completion:nil];
```

but the card is flip before to be to the new frame . Any ideea how can i resolve this >

Comment: just try by writing animateWithDuration: block inside transitionWithView: block

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a sequence of your animations. The simplest way to do it would be to put the flipping animation in completion block of frame change animation.

Example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                 animations:^{
                     self.image1.frame = CGRectMake(90,self.scrollView.frame.origin.y+40, 140, 250);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
                     //your flip animation goes here
                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code . may be help you for flip animation from right side.

```
[UIView transitionFromView:appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view
                            toView:appDelegate.navigationController.view
                          duration:0.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                        completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:appDelegate.navigationController];
         }];
```